# Typical size for breast tumor at the beginning and at the end of radiotherapy treatment

Tags: cancer, tumors, radiology, breast, radiation

I'd like to know if you know about sizes of breast tumors at the beginning and at the end of a typical radiotherapy treatment. I know that standard scheduled (50 Gy in 25 sessions) and hypofractionated (40-42 Gy in 15 sessions) could be used. But for example, in ductal carcinoma in situ or invasive what is the amount of reduction in tumor's size? or with others type of breast cancer. I know that it depends of the patient and other factors, but if you know some information and if it is documented I would thank you so much.